# PHP getting a value where key is between a range

Tags: php

Is there are any efficient way to get a value. where the key is between range?
for example. i want a value where the key is 13 or any range in that array that includes 13. as you can see the second element's range is 11-25. so i should get that value. because 11-25 also includes 13

```
$array = array(
    '0-10'   => 'a Value',
    '11-25'  => 'another Value',
    '26-50'  => 'value',
    '51-100' => 'another string'
);
```

Comment: take a look at function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: the key in that array is the range. i will give any number. the function will search for it in a range thats what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
function findInRange($number, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        list($min, $max) = explode('-', $key);

        if ($number >= $min && $number <= $max) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$number = 13;
$array = [
    '0-10' => 'a Value',
    '11-25' => 'another Value',
    '26-50' => 'value',
    '51-100' => 'another string'
];

$result = findInRange($number, $array);

var_dump($reesult);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be using the following approach with `array_map` and `explode` functions:

```
$search_key = 13;
$result = '';

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $range = array_map('intval', explode('-', $k));
    if ($search_key >= $range[0] && $search_key <= $range[1]) {
        $result = $v;
        break;
    }
}

print_r($result);  // "another Value"
```

Comment: thanks buddy, but if there is a range that is just a number instead of two numbers joined with "-".

Comment: oooops. sorry if there is only one number then i can make te like x-x or 13-13

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = 13;
$value = current(array_filter($array,
    function($key) use ($index) {
        if(!is_int(strpos('-', $key))){
            return $key == $index;
        }
        $range = explode('-', $key);
        return ($index >= $range[0] && $index <= $range[1]);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```